# Juego de memoria (memorama) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy haciendo un juego de memoria en Python entre 2 jugadores y usé matrices para estar sustituyendo datos entre matriz y matriz, una matriz de puros guiones y otra de números del 1 al 18 (secuencia que se repite 2 veces), ya esta casi terminado, sin embargo, le falta los siguientes puntos:

- En el momento en el que no haya más guiones por destapar(que ya se hayan destapado todos los guiones), le imprima 'Has ganado!' y que jugador ganó.
- Cuando el usuario ponga una coordenada en el que el guión ya está destapado, que le imprima ('Ya se destapó, ingresa otra coordenada') y que el programa continúe.

El primer punto iría en las funciones: "condiciones" y "condiciones2", porque ahí es en donde se diferencia entre jugador y jugador. El segundo punto lo pondría en las funciones "memorama" y "memorama2" justo abajo de cuando le pide x2 y y2. (Así es como yo creo que deberían estar localizados estos dos puntos, si crees que irían mejor en otra función, adelante!)

Sería un enorme favor si me pudieran ayudar! De verdad estuve todo el día pensando pero no se me ocurre nada, código:

```
import random
import sys

x=0
y=0
x2=0
y2=0
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
matrix = [['-','-','-','-','-','-'],['-','-','-','-','-','-'],['-','-','-','-','-','-'],['-','-','-','-','-','-'],['-','-','-','-','-','-'],['-','-','-','-','-','-']]
matrix2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18]]
guion = '-'
variable = 5

def memorama():
    imprimir()
    print('Jugador 1')

    x = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la horizontal: '))
    if x > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        memorama()

    y = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la vertical: '))
    if y > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        memorama()

    matrix[x][y] = matrix2[x][y]

    imprimir()

    x2 = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la horizontal: '))
    if x2 > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        matrix[x][y] = '-'
        memorama()
    else:
        y2 = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la vertical: '))
        if y2 > 5:
            print('ERROR')
            matrix[x][y] = '-'
            memorama()

    matrix[x2][y2] = matrix2[x2][y2]

    condiciones(x,y,x2,y2)

    imprimir()

def memorama2():
    imprimir()
    print('Jugador 2')

    x = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la horizontal: '))
    if x > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        memorama2()

    y = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la vertical: '))
    if y > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        memorama2()

    matrix[x][y] = matrix2[x][y]

    imprimir()

    x2 = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la horizontal: '))
    if x2 > 5:
        print('ERROR')
        matrix[x][y] = '-'
        memorama2()
    else:
        y2 = int(input('Ingresa un valor en la vertical: '))
        if y2 > 5:
            print('ERROR')
            matrix[x][y] = '-'
            memorama2()

    matrix[x2][y2] = matrix2[x2][y2]

    condiciones2(x,y,x2,y2)

    imprimir()

def condiciones(x,y,x2,y2):
    global p1
    if matrix[x][y] != matrix[x2][y2]:
        matrix[x2][y2] = "-"
        matrix[x][y] = "-"
        respuesta = str(input('¿Quiere seguir jugando? s/n: '))
        if respuesta == 's':
            memorama2()
        elif respuesta == 'n':
            print('El jugador tiene',p1,'pares')
            print('El jugador tiene',p2,'pares')
            if p1 > p2:
                print('El ganador fue el jugador 1')
            elif p2 > p1:
                print('El ganador fue el jugador 2')
            elif p2 == p1:
                print('Fue un empate!')
            elif p1 == p2:
                print('Fue un empate!')
            sys.exit()    
    else:
        p1 += 1 
        memorama()

def condiciones2(x,y,x2,y2):
    global p2
    if matrix[x][y] != matrix[x2][y2]:
        matrix[x2][y2] = "-"
        matrix[x][y] = "-"
        respuesta = str(input('¿Quiere seguir jugando? s/n: '))
        if respuesta == 's':
            memorama()

        elif respuesta == 'n':
            print(p1)
            print(p2)
            if p1 > p2:
                print('El jugador tiene',p1,'pares')
            elif p2 > p1:
                print('El jugador tiene',p2,'pares')
            elif p2 == p1:
                print('Fue un empate!')
            elif p1 == p2:
                print('Fue un empate!')
            sys.exit()
    else:
        p2 += 1
        memorama2()

def imprimir():
    contador = 0
    print('  0 1 2 3 4 5 \n')

    for i in range(6):
        print(contador, '', end = '')
        contador += 1
        for j in range(6):
            print((matrix[i][j]),'', end = '')

        print('\n')

def main():
    while variable == 5:
        random.shuffle(matrix2)
        for i in matrix2:
            random.shuffle(i)
        memorama()

main()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria el problema puntual dentro de tu codigo donde no podes hacer lo que necesitas?

Comment: Mencioné 2 puntos en donde especifiqué que me hace falta del código. El primer punto iría en las funciones: "condiciones" y "condiciones2", porque ahí es en donde se diferencia entre jugador y jugador. El segundo punto lo pondría en las funciones "memorama" y "memorama2" justo abajo de cuando le pide x2 y y2.

Comment: La información fundamental debes agregarla en tu pregunta y no como comentario de preferencia para que tu pregunta sea más completa, saludos!

Comment: acaso esto es el Modelo Tec21?